# Passing $_SESSION variable to another page through a href

Tags: php, session, href, shopping-cart

This is shopping online page that a user can add what products he wants in his shopping cart, but when the user clicks on view shopping cart i need to pass the variable $_SESSION['cart_Name'] to shoppingcart.php page, to retrieve the info from the database, i tried this code :

in onlineshop.php:

```
<a href="shoppingcart.php?si=<?php echo session_id; ?>"><img src="cartt.png" alt="ٍShopping Cart" style="width:40px;height:40px"><br/>Shopping Cart</a>
```

in shoppingcart.php:

```
   session_start();
    session_id($_GET['si']);
```

but it gave me this error:

```
Warning: Unknown: The session id is too long or contains illegal characters, valid characters are a-z, A-Z, 0-9 and '-,' in Unknown on line 0

Warning: Unknown: Failed to write session data (files). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (C:\xampp\tmp) in Unknown on line 0
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to pass it, you should just be able to access it through `$_SESSION['cart_Name']` on your `shoppingcart.php` page.

Comment: If something is in the session, there is zero need to pass it to another page. Every page can access the session by calling `session_start();` etc. In fact, passing session variables through the URL defeats the purpose of even using session variables.

Comment: as long as you also used `session_start();` on your first page then you can set $_SESSION['cart_Name'] on the first page and retrieve it on any subsequent pages that also include `session_start();` as the very first thing.  That is assuming you're not jumping to a different domain name during the process...?

Comment: I called the variable $_SESSION['cart_Name'] like this: `$qry = "SELECT * FROM shopping_cart WHERE Cart_Name='$_SESSION['cart_Name']';" ;` but it gave me this error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\sw\shoppingcart.php on line 7

Comment: umm thats a totally different issue - `$qry = "SELECT * FROM shopping_cart WHERE Cart_Name= '" . $_SESSION['cart_Name'] . "';" ;`

Answer (score 0):

A session id doesn't disappear between two pages, i wonder why you load a session from a $_GET variable.

Moreover, by modifying your URL and playing with ?si, people can steal another person's session, it's a security trouble.

if on page A.php you have

```
session_start();
$_SESSION["cartname"] = "foo";
<a href="B.php">click Me </a>
```

in your page B.php this code :

```
session_start();
echo $_SESSION["cartname"];
```

will display : foo

Best regards